# R : error in moving a Raster using Shift function: It does NOT move. Why?

Tags: r, polygon, raster, netcdf, shift

I have a nc file (which I can read it as a raster in R and ArcGIS) and a shapefile (polygon) for Canada.

When I open both files in ArcMap, it re-projects them on-fly and the polygon would be located on the right location:

[image]

Then, I use R to open and plot them using the code:

```
## set the working directory:
setwd("C:/Users/Desktop/Data")

## required libraries
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(ncdf4)

## reading the polygon:
My_study_area <- readOGR(dsn = ".", layer = "Canada_AB")

## create a connection to the downloaded NC file:
fn <- "tasmin_day_CanESM5_ssp126_r1i1p1f1_gn_21010101-23001231_cliped_AB.nc"
ncin <- nc_open(fn) 
ncin

## create a raster from the nc file:
fn_brick <- brick(fn) 
fn_brick
extent(fn_brick)
```

Here is the output:

```
class      : Extent
xmin       : 229.2188 
xmax       : 271.4062
ymin       : 39.06842
ymax       : 64.18258


## since it has 73,000 layers, let us only work on one layer: fn_brick[[1]]
```

**My Goal:**

```
## I want to shift this raster in the x direction for -177.1876 units:  
## why -177.1876 units ?
## because I know if I shift it for -177.1876 units, the raster and the polygon will be in the right place 

fn_brick_shifted <- shift(fn_brick[[1]], dx= -177.1876, dy= 0, filename="new_nc_file", format="GTiff", datatype='FLT4S', overwrite=T)

extent(fn_brick_shifted)
```

Despite shifting the raster, its extent is still remained unchanged:

```
class      : Extent
xmin       : 229.2188 
xmax       : 271.4062
ymin       : 39.06842
ymax       : 64.18258
```

However, let us plot them:

```
plot(fn_brick_shifted)
lines(My_study_area)
```

The result in the R is like this:

[image]

As can be seen, **the raster is NOT shifted**, therefore the polygon is not plotted on the right place.

However, we can see the coordinate info for the files:

For the raster:

```
crs(fn_brick_shifted)
CRS arguments:
 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

For the polygon:

```
crs(My_study_area)
CRS arguments:
 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

Did I make any mistake in using the **shift** function for the raster?

Do I need to employ another function for obtaining my goal?

Any comment or help would be highly appreciated.

If you think having the raster and polygon files may help, you could download them here in a zip file:

[nc and polygon.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pi9j4gy1lyb08va/nc%20and%20polygon.zip?dl=1)